# Where is the predictive text dictionary gone?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, keyboard, dictionary

Due to recent updates to 4.1.2 the personal dictionary vanished.

That is, `Settings -> Language & Input -> Samsung keyboard @-> Predictive text` has still the option `Personalized data`, but there is no way to inspect the dictionary. Instead I can now `Learn from Facebook | Gmail | Twitter`.

Where is the personal dictionary gone?